# Chopping (statering) sound with any bluetooth headset on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headset

Installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Honor MagicBook 16 (AMD Ryzen 5 5600H) and found that can't use any bluetooth audio device: tried SONY WH-CH510, Honor EarBuds X, JBL speaker. Devices connected ok, but sound is terrible: chops, stattering, sometimes no sound at all.
System info:
uname -r: 5.15.0-56-generic (tried kernel 5.15.0-58, kernel 6)

lsusb:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2b7e:b519 SunplusIT Inc HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0489:e0df Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 25a7:fa23 Areson Technology Corp 2.4G Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 27c6:5125 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix Fingerprint Device 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Tried both pulseaudio:

```
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 25
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: john
Host Name: honor
Server Name: pulseaudio
Server Version: 15.99.1
Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_04_00.6.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_04_00.6.analog-stereo
Cookie: af14:00cb
```

pulseaudio with Pipewire

```
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 81
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: john
Host Name: honor
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.65)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: bluez_output.74_45_CE_08_F8_07.a2dp-sink
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_04_00.6.analog-stereo
Cookie: 43fb:a915
```

What am I doing wrong? What can be done?

Comment: Are you using 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi at the same time?

Comment: Nope. Using 5 GHz, also tried with WiFi off and got the same result.